# Sorting in place & stable in linear time

Tags: algorithms, sorting, counting, in-place

Given an array with only 0 & 1. Can we have an algorithm which has **all** the following desirable characteristics-

- The algorithm runs in $O(n)$ time.
- The algorithm is stable.
- The algorithm sorts in place.

I know the algorithms if only 2 characteristics are required but want to know if all the three characteristics possible simultaneously or not? If yes, how?

Comment: What does `stable` mean when there is `only 0 & 1`?

Comment: Means the order of zeros relative to zeros and ones relative to ones is preserved after the sort.

Comment: [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.25.5554&rep=rep1&type=pdf) achieves stable zero/one sorting in O(n) _word operations_ (without a multiplication operation) with O(1) _words_ of auxiliary memory. ​ ​ ​ (See ​ "The elements are regarded ... produces 7v$\supseteq$2$^i$8." .) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ (continued ...) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (... continued) ​ ​ ​ I don't know whether-or-not that can be improved to O(n) _time_ or whether-or-not the space usage can be reduced, even for just usual-meaning-of-stable-sorting of elements of {0,1,2} with respect to the [total preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Total_preorders) ​ 0 < 1 $\sim$ 2 . ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​