# In-place linear sort of integers, again

Tags: time-complexity, sorting, space-complexity, in-place, linear-complexity

I am amazed by the many discussion regarding the **existence of any linear and in-place sorting algorithm**, and variants, see *e.g.*
[is-this-implementation-of-bucket-sort-considered-in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484483/is-this-implementation-of-bucket-sort-considered-in-place)
[is-counting-sort-in-place-stable-or-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222523/is-counting-sort-in-place-stable-or-not)
[sorting-in-linear-time-and-in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682100/sorting-in-linear-time-and-in-place)
[can-a-counting-sort-be-considered-in-place-when-the-problem-constrains-the-numbe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65522915/can-a-counting-sort-be-considered-in-place-when-the-problem-constrains-the-numbe/)
[fastest-in-place-sorting-algorithm-for-epochtime](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55866/fastest-in-place-sorting-algorithm-for-epochtime)
[in-place-and-out-place-sorting-meaning](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93996/in-place-and-out-place-sorting-meaning)
[fast-stable-almost-in-place-radix-and-merge-sorts](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93563/fast-stable-almost-in-place-radix-and-merge-sorts)
[sorting-in-place-stable-in-linear-time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69781/sorting-in-place-stable-in-linear-time)

I am even more amazed by the lack of a clear and definitive answer, due in part to the fact that ["in-place" is loosely defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).

I would therefore like to give it one more try, aiming at being more precise and rigorous, **with your help**.

Sorry if this is too redundant; if so, please do not hesitate to tell me where.

**Problem statement.**

Input: $n$ positive integers of values lower than $k$, with $k\le n$.

Output: the $n$ integer in non-decreasing order.

**Proposal.**

This is the closest to in-place and linear sorting algorithm that I could find. It relies on a variant of counting sort that parses the original array and counts occurrences of integers in-place, within this array. To do so, it swaps the content of cells that it modifies, and encodes cells that contain a counter by a negative integer. Then, it *prints* the result without storing it.

This is a python implementation, with comments explaining the details:

```
import random,sys
random.seed()

# create input
n = 30
k = 4
l = [random.randrange(0,k) for i in range(n)]

# for debug: print original list and its native sort
print(" ".join([str(x) for x in l]))
print(" ".join([str(x) for x in sorted(l)]))

# "in-place" counting sort
i = 0
while i<n:
  x = l[i]      # the value to count
  if l[x]<0:    # there alreaty is a counter for it
    l[x] -= 1   # (negatively) increment it
    l[i] = -1   # set current cell to 0, encoded as -1
  else:         # first occurrence of x
    l[i] = l[x] # store the value in l[w] before erasing it
    l[x] = -2   # new counter in l[x], init to 1, encoded as -2
  while i<n and l[i]<0: # go to next non-counter cell
    i += 1

# print result
# l[i]=-x-1 means there are x occurrences of i
for i in range(k):
  for j in range(-l[i]-1):
    sys.stdout.write("%d "%i)
sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

**Remarks.**

This algorithm **seems to be in-place**, since it seems to only use a constant amount of memory in addition to its input.

However, **it is not really in-place**, because:

- It uses negative numbers to encode counter information within the input array, which actually costs $n$ bits.
- Its output is just printed, not stored (not even in the original array) and so it is not available for further computations.

**Questions.**

A first set of questions is about **possible improvements**:

- Is it possible to save even more space? For instance, only $k$ bits are really needed, as there are $k$ counters. Anything else?
- Is it possible to write the sorted values in the input array? or may we prove that this is not possible?
- Is it possible to extend it to more general inputs? Clearly, any other integer interval of length at most $k$ is possible. Anything else?

A second set of questions is about **possible uses**:

- Are there cases where one wants to print the result, without storing it? It seems related to streaming algorithms.
- Does this algorithm help in finding better solutions to other problems, like median or cumulative distribution computations? or removing duplicate values?

Comment: Read this: https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.4107

Comment: Thanks, interesting reference that indeed answers some of my questions :) They seem to have an implementation; do you know if it is available?